# inserting a new data in db using express post method

Tags: node.js, express, post, methods, sequelize.js

I want to insert a data into db using sequelize express, the below code is working properly, but I want to create a files like controller, config, routes, models like that and postman tool.. I've tried more but I didn't get proper output.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '100mb', 
parameterLimit: 1000000 }));

const sequelize = new Sequelize('ganeshdb', 'root', 'welcome123$', 
{
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  dialect: 'mysql'
});
const users = sequelize.define('users', {
  id: {
    primarykey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  role: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING
});
app.post('/test', function (request, response) {
  return users.create({
    id: request.body.id,
    name: request.body.name,
    role: request.body.role,
    email: request.body.email
  }).then(function (users) {
    if (users) {
      response.send(users);
    } else {
      response.status(400).send('Error in insert new  record');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3001, function () {
console.log('Express server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Example:

```
npm install express-generator -g
express --view=pug myapp
```

And you can see more https://solidgeargroup.com/clean-architecture-in-nodejs

Comment: i think i send my project to ur mail, plz check and give correct code

Comment: I can only do this in 4 hours

Comment: i am waiting for ur response

Comment: I'm sent you an answer to your question